# Python Selenium Webdriver Wait until Element is Loaded

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.7

The idea is to scrape a Website. By doing so, I wanted to scrape it via screenshots and then extract the data off the screenshot. Because in the Data I wanted to scrape is not in the HTML-Code and to be honest I didn't know how to handle it ( I am pretty new to python/programming).

It is working fine so far, but I had the problem that WebDriverWait doesn't work properly. 
That's the Webpage: https://exporo.de/investment/betreutes-wohnen-huerth and in detail it's this dynamic part:

```
<div class="key">Bereits investiert</div>
<div class="value"
     ng-controller="pubSubController as pubSubCtrl"
     ng-show="pubSubCtrl.hasProject(2385)"
     ng-bind="pubSubCtrl.getProject(2385, 'total')"></div>
```

So this is my code so far(the loop of it):

```
while AktuellerWert1 < Endwert1:
        Zeit = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        driver1.get_screenshot_as_file(png_link % FileName1)

        img = Image.open(png_link % FileName1)
        PNG1 = image_to_string(img)
        PNG1_bearb = PNG1.split()
        AktuellerWert1 = PNG1_bearb[PNG1_bearb.index('investiert') + 1]
        Endwert1 = PNG1_bearb[PNG1_bearb.index('Finanzierungsziel') + 1]

        if AnfangsWert1 != AktuellerWert1:
            with open("/Users/davidoverbeck/Dropbox/Screen/Exporo/%s.csv" % FileName1, 'a') as csvFile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                writer.writerow([AktuellerWert1, Zeit])
            print(AktuellerWert1)
        else:
            pass
        AnfangsWert1 = AktuellerWert1

        driver1.refresh()

        element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/section[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[10]/div[2]')))
    else:
        with open("/Users/davidoverbeck/Dropbox/Screen/Abgeschlossen.csv", 'a') as csvFile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
            writer.writerow([Zeit, FileName1])
        print(FileName1, 'abgeschlossen')
        driver1.close()
```

It's working fine for 2 minutes and then it gives me the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
>   (no message behind it?!)

I am not sure whether the loop does anything at all or, in case it's working, what's wrong with it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that the data you're looking for is here:

https://exporo.de/pubsub/initial .

In that case no need to parse html, you will need to parse the json.

See F12 -> network tab -> Type column = json

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes thats what i was looking for.. but i want to parse the side quite frequently.. is it posslibe to parse those json files regulary without being blocked by the firewall? ...

Comment: Sure, but make sure that you don't scrape like 10 times per minute, that will be noticed.

Comment: Ok cool! Thank you so much. One last thing.. I couldnt follow your advice with the f12.. i am using a mac.. I have to get to the network tab in chrome? Or what did you exactly mean?

Comment: Yes it's the network tab in chrome or any browser. Don't know how to get there on the Mac!

Comment: Thank you :) you made my day!

Comment: If you feel this answer could be useful for other developers, do not hesitate to upvote.